# How to use multiple methods in JavaScript at the same time

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I have an input where you can search for a specific course by its name, for this I use filtering, and also the `includes()` method, my problem is that I need to apply three methods at the same time, the first method is `toLowerCase()`, the second is `toUpperCase()` and the last method is `trim()`

```
GetMyCourses() {
  return this.courses.filter(value => {
    return value.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.result);
  });
},
```

If you leave the `toLowerCase` method, then it does not give capital names when searching, and vice versa, in addition, if you remove these two methods, then when searching you will need to accurately search for the word

Comment: You could do this with array `some`, but here you certainly don't need it. It's like the answer says

Comment: *How to use multiple methods in JavaScript at the same time* use regex, `.filter(value => new RegExp(search, "i").test(value.title))`, `search` being something you made safe or built from some logic https://playcode.io/823069/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert `this.result` to lower case as well.

```
GetMyCourses() {
  let result = this.result.toLowerCase()
  return this.courses.filter(value => {
    return value.title.toLowerCase().includes(result);
  });
},
```

Comment: Or just `value.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.result.toLowerCase())`...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yeah, but that converts `this.result` multiple times unnecessarily.

Comment: Meh. 99% of the time that's not going to be a problem. If you want to micro-optimize, you should have a `value.searchableTitle` property that is already lower-cased...

Comment: I also like to do it just to keep the expression less complex.